# How do I join two elements and then render them in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's simple. I have a render function with two elements

```
render() {
  let elem1 = <div>Foo</div>;
  let elem2 = <div>Bar</div>;
  return(elem1 + elem2); // How do I render elem1 below elem2?
}
```

I want the output to be equivalent to this

```
<div>
  Foo
</div>
<div>
  Bar
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple like this:

```
render() {
  let elem1 = <div>Foo</div>;
  let elem2 = <div>Bar</div>;
  return (
    <div>
      {elem1}
      {elem2}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You should read and practice more JSX in [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using React > 16.2 you can use the new [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) component

```
  render() {
    let elem1 = <div>Foo</div>;
    let elem2 = <div>Bar</div>;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {elem1}
        {elem2}
      <React.Fragment/>
  );
}
```

The main advantage over using a div is that it doesn't add any elements to the page and is more readable than returning an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    let elements=new Array();
    elements.push(<div>Foo</div>);
    elements.push(<div>Bar</div>);
   return elements;
}
```

So basically you can return array of children.

Answer (score 0):

You can just return the two elements in the render method instead of declaring them and return them directly. Like this

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>Foo</div>
            <div>Bar</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @Martin's answer above: If you are starting with latest version of React you should try and use `React.Fragment` as grouping element. Here is the reactjs documentation for it: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

There is also a shorter syntax for `React.Fragment` which is `<>{elements}</>`. However support for short syntax is not fully available yet.

Here is a codepen link for problem you are trying to solve: https://codepen.io/bdevapatla/pen/QxaKEq